# Can't get jeditbale ajax call to work

Tags: jquery, ajax, jeditable

I am trying to edit text inline and I am using jeditable plugin, but I have been unable to get to save the new data properly using ajax call. I can edit the text but after refresh it goes back to the old text.

Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.editable').editable(function(value, settings) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "url"
            data: $("#edit").val(),
            success: function(event) {
            }
        });
     return(value);

  }, {
         indicator : 'Saving...',
         tooltip   : 'Click to edit...',
         type    : 'text',       


 });
 });
```

Html:

```
<h2 class="editable" id="edit">edit this</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not submitting any data. Replace

```
$("#edit").val()
```

with

```
$("#edit").text()
```

`.val()` only works on form elements - see http://api.jquery.com/val/. `<h2>` is not a form element.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now if I want to attach the new at the end of the url, any suggestions how might I do that i tried " +$("#edit").text()" at the of the url but that didn't work

Comment: why do you want to put it at the end of the url? You're doing a POST, so the value should be passed in the request body, which is done in jQuery ajax by making it the "data" parameter, which you've already done. Unless you mean some different URL?

Comment: I need to send "url/id/newtext" for it to save the new text after the edit, it is the way the function is asking for it. I tried to send it in data and it didn't work. When i go manually to "url/id/newtext" in browser and attach new text at the end it works

Comment: so it should be a GET as well, instead of a POST?